# "scala" command terminates batch scripts

Tags: scala, scripting, command, prompt, terminate

during my work here I collided with a somewhat peculiar problem. It's possible that there is a highly simple explanation for this behaviour, but to me it just doesn't make much sense.

Here's the situation:

I wrote a batch file "test.bat" that, right now, looks like this:

```
echo 1
scala myProgram
echo 2
```

When I open the command prompt in the according directory and run test.bat, it starts by echoing 1, then runs myProgram (which also has certain outputs that appear in the console, so the scala program myProgram works properly) - and then stops. 2 does *not* appear in the console and the console waits for me to input another command.

Why this behaviour? Is is a malfunction of the console? Or of the scala command? Or not a malfunction at all and it is actually meant to behave that way?

What I was actually trying to do is redirecting the output of "scala myProgram" to a file (which works well) and rename this file after the scala program has terminated, so my batch file originally looked somewhat like this:

```
scala myProgram > log.txt 2>&1
ren "log.txt" "log2.txt"
```

And I was confused about the fact that "log2.txt" was never created.

Your answers are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does your Scala program actually *exit* itself ?

Comment: The scala program is simply a class containing a main function which is automatically executed when I call "scala myProgram". The very last command of this main function is a println, which appears in the console as intended.

Comment: Could you provide the Scala code you are using? Or try again with something really simple like this:  
    `object myProgram extends App {
    println("hello stackoverflow")
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-nc` to scala command worked for me:

```
    $ scala -nc /tmp/2.scala
    Hello world
```

So I guess, the issue has something to do with the compilation daemon

```
 -nc          no compilation daemon: do not use the fsc offline compiler
```

Could you try that?